# Generate Dynamic URL based on User Selection in Django

Tags: html, django-views, django-forms

I am very new to Django and would appreciate any help.

Scenario: User selects (A, B, C or D) from a dropdown menu (using forms.Select widget in Django) and clicks a Submit button. On the button click:

1. Based on user's selection, **dynamically generate** a URL e.g. localhost/**D**
2. I plan to capture the selection D in the URL using regular expression (`r'^(\w+)/$'`) and generate the corresponding view.

**Where am I stuck**: I can't seem to find a way to *dynamically generate* the URL and redirect to it via button click. Since the button is HTML tag and will have href to the dynamically generated URL, I don't know how to achieve this.